# custom posts query being overrided - showing standard posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Stumped by this one.. Something seems to be interfering with my wp_query on a page template. The query is for a custom post type but it's bringing up standard posts, and if I echo the query it looks like it's been reset. On the other hand, the query_posts function works fine with the same $args.

My code for the page template:

```
    <?php 
    $args = ['post-type' => 'electives', 'category' => 'esl', 'post-status' => 'publish']; 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?> 

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But this is the request delivered to the page:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```